# How to solve the following error in python: "IndexError: string index out of range"

Tags: python, python-3.x, index-error

I have written a python code which gives the following error `"IndexError: string index out of range"`

Please tell me how to fix this error.

```py
actuallink = 'http://www.exxonmobilperspectives.com'
slashcounter = 0
indexslash = 0
while slashcounter < 3:
    if(actuallink[indexslash] == '/'):
        slashcounter = slashcounter + 1
    indexslash = indexslash + 1
    PLink = actuallink[:indexslash - 1]
```

PS. When I change the link to anything else, it works perfectly

Comment: The link you provided doesn't have 3 slashes, so the `while` loop will not stop incrementing `indexslash` so it will eventually become too high for the string.

Comment: what is the final desired outcome of this?

Comment: @AvivShai , shouldn't the while loop automatically exit after it has indexed to the last character?

Comment: No. It continues until 3 is hit for slashcounter. You need an additional guard that accounts for len(actuallink)

Comment: @QHarr I want to extract the "http://" part from the link. I have an array of links and this link is one of that

Comment: @QHarr could you please suggest an update to the while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
actuallink = 'http://www.exxonmobilperspectives.com'
endPoint = len(actuallink.split('/')) - 1
if endPoint > 0:
    slashcounter = 0
    indexslash = 0
    while slashcounter < endPoint:
        if(actuallink[indexslash] == '/'):
            slashcounter = slashcounter + 1
        indexslash = indexslash + 1
        PLink = actuallink[:indexslash]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
actuallink = 'http://www.exxonmobilperspectives.com'
slashcounter = 0
indexslash = 0
while indexslash < len(actuallink):
    if(actuallink[indexslash] == '/'):
        slashcounter = slashcounter + 1
        print("Slash number {},Index ={}".format(slashcounter,indexslash))
    indexslash = indexslash + 1
    PLink = actuallink[:indexslash - 1]
print("Slashcounter = {}".format(slashcounter))
```

The result :

```
Slash number 1,Index =5
Slash number 2,Index =6
Slashcounter = 2
```